# Importing a non-WP database and search engine into WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a MySQL database and a javascript form that accesses it via php. My database and search form have been handed over to a developer who wants to turn them into a WordPress site. (Please do not ask me why.) The developer claims that he can convert my database and php functions into a WordPress plug-in. So far, however, his plug-in has not come close to returning correct search results. My question is whether the problem is WordPress or the developer. Is this something that WordPress can do?

Comment: I'm going to go with Developer here. There is work to make complex php and javascript "Wordpress-y". It's not easy work, but there is nothing limiting the implementation from a wordpress/php/javsacript/mysql perspective.

Comment: Yeah, this could be done. Easiest way would be to slightly modify the original code into a WordPress plugin and then add some kind of template to show the results within the WordPress website/template. I guess it wouldn't be all that hard. Would this be an elegant solution? Probably not. I really wonder why you'd want this... could you shine a light on what kind of data the database contains -- i.e. what kind of stuff do you keep in there?

Comment: I guess the potentially-odd-part here is... Is there already a wordpress install for this site, and this is just incorporating the new code to be part of the CMS, or is the developer just shoving this into a new wordpress install for fun? Like... if there is no current wordpress implementation, this would be a strange reason to make one (unless the plan is to scale the site into a CMS for future development/end user ease-of-use).

Comment: As I said, I can't tell you why the developer wants to do it. I'm working with him at arm's length through a higher-up in my organization. All we really needed was a CSS style sheet to make my search results look pretty. My suspicion is that he's a WP developer who just does everything in WP and didn't want to deal with HTML and CSS.  The database contains information on about 6K organizations, and the php functions search for them by their location, services they provide, and keywords in their titles.

Comment: @JNevill: Nope, there is no pre-existing WordPress site into which he is trying to incorporate this, nor any plans to build anything around it.

Comment: To elaborate on my earlier comment, and the one made by @JNevill, in light of your latest comment; this makes absolutely no sense to put into a WordPress install. If the code is already working and there's already some (good enough) way to manage the data, I see no reason to incorporate this into a CMS, especially not one that's originally designed for keeping a blog website. I also see no point of proposing porting to WordPress if all the client's asking for is an addition/update of (the) style.

Comment: @David Then this seems like a strange thing to do. There are definite perks for moving to a CMS, but if this is just a one-off php and done website then I can't imagine a reason to add all of the overhead of a CMS. It's like launching a cruise ship to get a family of four across Lake Michigan. Perhaps it's some corporate-wide decision that all "websites" this particular group works on have to be in wordpress. Which would be insane, but having worked in corporate environment for years would totally not be surprising.

Comment: @JNevill. That's what I assumed, but I've never used WP, so my opinion didn't carry any weight. Maybe yours will. Thanks!